# ssh with identity_file failed on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ssh, openssh

First I generate RSA key on the target host on ubuntu 20.04:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Then I scp `~/.ssh/id_rsa` to source host.
Final I wanna to ssh from source host by `id_rsa`:

```
ssh -i id_rsa root@target_host
```

But login failed

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you run `ssh-keygen -t rsa` from your user account, or as `root`? Keys are specific to a user, not to the machine as a whole. Is `PermitRootLogin` set appropriately on the source host?

Comment: Please clarify: "Then I scp ~/.ssh/id_rsa to source host"? You cannot simply `scp` it somewhere. You have to add your public key to a new line in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file on the target host. Or simply use `ssh-copy-id` that does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it actually the other way round. You need to create a keypair on the local (*source*) machine first, then copy that to the remote (*target*) host.
这事你操作反了，你需要在本地计算机上创建密钥，并将其复制到远程计算机。

1a. create the local keyfile (you can pick from two algorithms):

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

1b. or with the common 4096bit encryption:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096
```

2a. then copy your public SSH key to the remote machine:

```
ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_ed25519.pub
```

2b. or with the common encryption

```
sh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

then enter your (*remote machine*) password when prompted and follow the instructions.